# Windows 10 Pro vs Home for asp.net developer

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm going to set up Windows for some .NET development and wondering if I need to buy *Pro* version, or *Home* edition will be enough. 
I've checked this [comparison](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/Compare) and a couple of other articles.

Can't find any information about restrictions for .NET development. Are there any? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be fine with the Home edition

According to this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/whats-the-difference-between-windows-10-home-and/55338b22-d042-45cb-b9c9-a1be21b534e1?auth=1), these are the Home Edition features:

> - PCs, tablets and 2-in-1s
> - Cortana Assistant
> - Microsoft Edge web browser
> - Continuum tablet mode for touch-capable devices
> - Windows Hello face-recognition, iris and fingerprint login
> - universal Windows apps like Photos, Maps, Mail, Calendar, Music and Video
> - Ability to capture and share game play for XBOX One owners
> - Mounting/Reading of Bitlocker Encrypted drives

The Pro edition offers these extra features:

> - PCs, tablets and 2-in-1s
> - Cortana Assistant
> - Microsoft Edge web browser
> - Continuum tablet mode for touch-capable devices
> - Windows Hello face-recognition, iris and fingerprint login
> - universal Windows apps like Photos, Maps, Mail, Calendar, Music and Video
> - Ability to capture and share game play for XBOX One owners
> - **Domain Join Services**
> - **BitLocker Drive Encryption**
> - **Remote Access Services**
> - **Group Policy editor**
> - **Windows Update for Business**
> - **Hyper-V Virtualization**

So unless you need one the highlighted features, I think you should just be fine with the Home edition

EDIT: Hyper-V might come in handy when deploying/testing applications.

Comment: Don't forget lack of Hyper-V in Home edition. .NET developers requiring integrated UWP debugging experience will want one, but it isn't necessary for pure ASP.NET development.

Comment: Good point! Editted my post.

Comment: `Windows 10 Home` allows you to mount a Bitlocker encrypted drive it just does not allow you to disable or enable the encryption on said drive.  This has been the case since Windows Vista.

Comment: @ramhound That's what the answer says, 'drive encryption' for the pro edition.

Comment: Most people don't know the difference.